# How To Fix Unicode Character Issues On iTunes Feed

Tags: php, unicode, app-store, itunes-sdk, unicode-normalization

I am trying to pull applications from the Apple App Store using their authorised flat feed. However, I am having a tough time dealing with the encoding issues. Here are some examples :

A *Japanese* app titled

> ホームページ用和英辞典

is displayed as

> ãƒ›ãƒ¼ãƒ ãƒšãƒ¼ã‚¸ç”¨å’Œè‹±è¾žå

Not just that, even commonly used special characters like '(apostrophe), “(quote) are displayed with characters like â€™ and â€œ.

Can someone please help me with how this issue can be sorted out?

Edited to Add : I am working on PHP

Comment: That is actually japanese, but not that it matters :)

Comment: That app name is Japanese not Chinese.

Comment: Thanks guys. Have edited the original post :-)

Answer (score 0):

What character set is the feed provided in, and what character set are you declaring your document to be? It's pretty common for people starting out to be sending ISO-8859-1, while reading in a UTF-8 feed. You'll want those two to match for simplicity.

These two articles may also be of interest while dealing with these issues

- http://phpadvent.org/2009/character-sets-by-paul-reinheimer
- http://seancoates.com/blogs/tag/unicode

Comment: Thanks preinheimer. Just realized that I had made a mistake in declaring the headers UTF-8. It was a pretty minor mistake but hadn't spotted until now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are either not retaining the original character coding or you are outputting Unicode into a non Unicode coded stream.

Comment: Thanks Koan. You are right. There was in fact a mistake in declaring the headers in UTF-8. I have been able to fix it now.